# Были в конторе старые висячие стенные часы. Почему здесь определение неоднородны?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация, синтаксис

Были в конторе старые висячие стенные часы. Почему здесь определение неоднородны? Помогите понять. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере между определениями нельзя вставить союз *и* : "старые, висячие и стенные часы". Все словосочетание разбивается на три слоя : старые ((висячие (стенные часы)). Определения не связаны общим смыслом, а характеризуют предмет с совершенно разных точек.
[В качестве справки.](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_3_2)

Однородные определения : старые, подержанные и истертые часы.

Answer (score 2):

ПРАВИЛО

ОДНОРОДНЫЕ определения раскрывают одну общую тему, создают общий образ. Они обозначают сходные или сближенные в данном тексте признаки и обычно выражаются качественными прилагательными, например: Наступила ясная, тёплая погода. Снова потянулись длинные, однообразные дни. По обеим  сторонам дороги неподвижно стоят старые, печальные берёзы.

НЕОДНОРОДНЫЕ определения характеризуют предмет с разных сторон и выражаются различными видами прилагательных: качественными, относительными, притяжательными, а также их различными сочетаниями. Определения, выраженные качественными прилагательными, являются неоднородными, если они обозначают разные признаки, не раскрывающие общую тему, например размер и форму, цвет и размер.   Примеры: маленькое овальное  зеркало, старый деревянный дом, пушистый лисий хвост.

РЕШЕНИЕ
 Старые висячие стенные часы - все признаки разные, общей темы нет, поэтому прилагательные неоднородные.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае определения являются неоднородными, так как предшествующее относится не непосредственно к определяемому существительному, а к сочетанию последующего определения и определяемого существительного:

стенные часы - висячие + стенные часы (хотя непонятно, как стенные часы могут быть не висячими) - старые + висячие стенные часы.

Подробнее см. здесь:http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/85/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Если  неоднородные определения выражаются качественными и относительными прилагательными, то качественные прилагательные предшествуют относительным. Но это вовсе не определение неоднородных прилагательных, а следствие из того, что они неоднородные. К примеру: тонкая длинная нить и длинная тонкая нить, здесь качественные прилагательные можно менять местами. Какое вы тогда дадите им определение?

Comment: Не поняла вопроса. Я ничего не говорила о качественных и относительных прилагательных. Здесь стенные часы - единое понятие, как напольные часы. Висячие стенные часы, видимо, разновидность стенных. Движение от родового понятия к видовому. А старые - дополнительный признак. Как старая глянцевая напольная плитка. В "тонкая длинная нить" определения относятся непосредственно к существительному, а не к словосочетанию.

Comment: Из современного учебника для вузов (2013 год): "Неоднородные определения называют логически неодноплановые признаки предмета, характеризующие его с разных сторон, по разным параметрам". Далее следует информация об относительных и качественных прилагательных, при этом ни слова не сказано о родовых и видовых понятиях".

Comment: София, мое объяснение о присоединении определения к словосочетанию "определение + существительное", а не непосредственно к существительному (без оглядки на качественное/относительное) взято из самого полного учебника по пунктуации - Розенталь, "Пунктуация". Родово-видовое к примеру с часами, возможно, и не подходит (все-таки висячие часы не разновидность стенных), но "старые" и "висячие" присоединяются к "стенные часы", а не к "часы".

Comment: Пример с плиткой показательнее: глянцевая и матовая плитка - видовые понятия по отношению к "напольная плитка". Базовое словосочетание в подобных примерах - терминологическое, родовое название, к которому могут присоединяться как видовые, так и более свободные признаки. Критерий, предложенный Розенталем, по-моему, простой и удобный, и тут не важно, качественные прилагательные или относительные.

Comment: Tat, да неудобно это - решать грамматические задачи с помощью орфогр. справочника, легче и лучше наоборот. Удобно определить грамматику, а потом говорить о знаках препинания. Последовательность действий такова: 1) формулировка понятия "однор. и неоднор. определения". 2)Применение этого определения к различным видам прилагат.: кач. и отн. прилаг. всегда неоднородны. 3)Построение словосочетания по типу А) кач.прилаг.+ (отн.прилаг. + сущееств.)или Б) кач.прилаг.+ кач.прилаг.+ существ. Вот сложный пример: "Это был типичный (добрый, простодушный) русский человек". Где тут род и вид? Запутаешься.